# Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python

Tags: python, performance, beginner, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

This is yet another take in Python for the infamous Sieve of Eratosthenes. I am a beginner in Python so any criticism is highly appreciated.

```
# Find primes until this integer.. Modify to your taste..
upper_bound = 1000

# Pass a list of integers and a prime number, 
# will return you a list where numbers divisible by the prime you passed are removed.
def remove_non_primes(list_of_ints, prime_to_check_against):
    multiplier = 1
    while prime_to_check_against * multiplier < list_of_ints[-1]:
        multiplier += 1
        # Should be quite fast since list is sorted.
        if prime_to_check_against * multiplier in list_of_ints:
            list_of_ints.remove(prime_to_check_against * multiplier)
    return list_of_ints


ints = list(range(2, upper_bound)) # Generate initial list of integers

# Initial prime for bootstrap
prime = 2 
# Keep track of iteration count, so we know the next prime to work with in each iteration.
iteration_count = 0 

while True:
    # Use length of list to determine we removed everything we could by 
    # checking this length against returning lists length.
    original_list_length = len(ints)
    # Do the magic, remove all non primes found by parameter prime.
    ints = remove_non_primes(ints, prime)
    # List was not modified.. Nothing to remove.
    if original_list_length == len(ints): 
        break
    iteration_count += 1
    prime = ints[iteration_count]

print(ints)
```

Are there any modifications that will dramatically increase the performance?

Comment: I have rolled back your lastedit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I question the following comment:

```
    # Should be quite fast since list is sorted.
    if prime_to_check_against * multiplier in list_of_ints:
        list_of_ints.remove(prime_to_check_against * multiplier)
```

Why will this be fast, due to the sorted list?  `x in list` doesn't understand that the list is sorted, nor does the `remove(x)`.  No binary searching will be done; just a straight linear search.  Not fast.

---

<strike>I also question the following comment:</strike>

```
    # List was not modified.. Nothing to remove.
    if original_list_length == len(ints): 
        break
```

Just because no multiples of `29` may remain in the list does not necessarily mean there are no multiples of `31`!  The proper stopping condition is when you reach `sqrt(upper_bound)`.

---

You are attempting to remove numbers you've already removed:

```
multiplier = 1
while prime_to_check_against * multiplier < list_of_ints[-1]:
    multiplier += 1
    if prime_to_check_against * multiplier in list_of_ints:
        list_of_ints.remove(prime_to_check_against * multiplier)
```

When you remove multiples of `13`, for instance, you are starting by removing `13*2`, and `13*3`, and `13*4`, and so on.

But you have already removed all the multiples of primes lower than `13`.  You should start at `13*13`,

```
    multiplier = prime_to_check_against
    while prime_to_check_against * multiplier <= list_of_ints[-1]:
        if prime_to_check_against * multiplier in list_of_ints:
            list_of_ints.remove(prime_to_check_against * multiplier)
        multiplier += 1
```

---

Finding and then removing.  You are searching the list twice: once to check if it exists, a second time to find it in order to remove it.

Instead, you could simply removed the item.

```
    try:
        list_of_ints.remove(prime_to_check_against * multipler)
    except ValueError:
        pass # it wasn't there
```

---

Even numbers as a special case.

```
ints = [2] + list(range(3, upper_bound, 2)) # Generate initial list of odd integers

# Initial prime for bootstrap
prime = 3
iteration_count = 1
```

And then, instead of increasing the multiplier by 1, you can increase it by 2, so you'd search `13*13`, `13*15`, `13*17`, ...

```
        multiplier += 2
```

---

Skip all of the multiplications, and just increment by `2*prime_to_check_against`

```
    multiple  = prime_to_check_against * prime_to_check_against
    increment = prime_to_check_against * 2 
    while multiple <= list_of_ints[-1]:
        try:
            list_of_ints.remove(multiple)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        multiple += increment
```

Or more pythonically:

```
    for multiple in range(prime_to_check_against * prime_to_check_against,
                          list_of_ints[-1]+1, 2*prime_to_check_against):
        try:
            list_of_ints.remove(multiple)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

---

Instead of populating a list with all of the candidate numbers, and then removing multiples of prime numbers from the list, which involves expensive list manipulations, you could:

- create a `bytearray(upper_bound)` to store prime/not-prime flags
- flag all multiples of prime numbers, as you find them, as not-prime
- use list-comprehension to extract the indexes which are flagged as prime

Using a `bytearray` is very efficient memory-wise, and indexing into the `bytearray` to set or test a flag is a very fast \$O(1)\$ operation.

I'm trying to decide whether to post my 10-lines of code for the sieve here, or let you attempt it based on the above hints.  Let me know if you need it.

Comment: Even numbers as a special case: Very good suggestion thank you, but I think Exception Handling is quite expensive, isnt it?

Comment: What do you mean `When you remove 13`? I never remove 13..

Comment: Sorry - when you remove **multiples of** 13.

Comment: No; exception handling in Python is very cheap.  "It is better to try and ask forgiveness than to ask for permission" is a common idiom in Python for this reason.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I will start a bounty just to give you more rep, but need a few days, cant start immediately. Thanks again.

Comment: Unless you are trying for the [Promoter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/220/promoter) or [Benefactor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/221/benefactor) badges, no bounty is necessary.  Besides, you look in need of more rep than I.  Still, I won’t say “no” to +15 for accepting my answer, but wait for a few days first to see if anyone else has any feedback.

Comment: Should I implement binary search myself would you say?

Comment: Can you tell me a case where `# List was not modified.. Nothing to remove.` will cause a problem? I think your comment on that one is not accurate and I think this stopping condition is just fine.

Comment: If you want practice writing a binary search, go ahead.  But it comes standard with python.  See: [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html).

Comment: “List not modified” would be a **necessary** condition for a stopping condition.  The question is, is it a **sufficient** condition?  I don’t know.  Still, in order to test the condition, you have to go through the sieve elimination step.  You can compute and store `sqrt(upper_bound)`, and use that as a stopping condition, and stop _before_ going through the elimination step and finding the length unchanged.   So not only is it not questionable, it would be faster.

Comment: Ok.  I’ve convinced myself, it is also a sufficient condition.  The composite number `prime**2` will always exist in the sieve, as long as `prime <= sqrt(upper_bound)`, so at least one number will be removed per iteration.

Comment: Actually prime ** 1 is removed always, not ** 2.

Comment: What do you think about the updated version?

Comment: I think that looks like a new question.  See: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)